# TypeScript compiler include node modules

Tags: typescript, node-modules

I'm attempting to compile a TypeScript project with the v2 RC, but the compiler appears to be including files that I have no interest in compiling. This is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "outDir": "../dist/core"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Then I simply run: `tsc --project tsconfig.json`. My code compiles but I get:

> node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js(201,5): error TS7027: Unreachable code detected.
>   ../node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/parser.js(18,21): error TS7027: Unreachable code detected.
>   ../node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/parser.js(386,13): error TS7027: Unreachable code detected.
>   ../node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/compiler/parser.js(573,21): error TS7027: Unreachable code detected.

Right enough, looking at those files there is unreachable code, but I don't really care about them - they are written to their own style.

How can I exclude those files? I've tried various options for the `exclude` option such as `../node_modules`, `../node_modules/**` etc, all with no luck.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like the allowJs : true option is causing errors.  The errors are pointing to .js files in the node_modules directory.  Can you exclude it ?

Comment: agreed.  allowJs compiles referenced javascript files with your typescript files.

Comment: use `files:` attribute to specify the files to include

Comment: I use `allowJs` at the moment while converting existing code to TypeScript. However, just enabling that option doesn't explain why its including files from node_modules.

Comment: @entre: What `files` option? I don't see one in the [list of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). Having said that, I'm really running this through gulp and it does give `tsc` the correct list of files. The `tsc` command above was me trying to simplify the problem as much as possible, and I removed gulp to see if I could eliminate gulp as the issue, which I did.

Comment: @entre: Stupid me. In the tsconfig not the compiler options.. I've just tried that, and also tried using the `exclude` and `include` options in the v2 RC, but with no luck. Its always seems to be including the node modules for some reason.